# Member variable of functor called from a Boost signals2 signal does not update

Tags: c++, boost, signals-slots, functor

I expect the following complete program to output the number `42`, but it outputs `0`. Why?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/signals2/signal.hpp>

class TestFunctor {
public:
    TestFunctor() : last_received_value(0) {}
    void operator()(const int& i) {
        last_received_value = i;
    };

    int last_received_value;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    TestFunctor f;
    boost::signals2::signal<void(const int& i)> sig;
    sig.connect(f);
    sig(42);
    std::cout << f.last_received_value << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

If `main()` were replaced with the following, I get the expected output `42`:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    TestFunctor f;
    f(42);
    std::cout << f.last_received_value << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I suspect the issue is that a copy of the `TestFunctor` instance is actually being hooked up to the signal. How can I prevent this (or is it even possible)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to register the callback by ref:

```
sig.connect(boost::ref(f));
```

Otherwise, the slot gets a copy of the functor `f` and the copy is updated.